# Postgres First Replica has expected safe_wal_size, 2nd replica does not

Tags: postgresql, replication

Using Postgres 14 on Ubuntu:

I have logical replication setup from **master** => **slave** => **slave2**;  It is replicating, but there is a problem with `safe_wal_size`.

Using `du -sh  /var/lib/postgresql/14`

1. After loading one 4GB SQL file, **master** is using 9.2GB of space
2. After replication becomes up to date **slave** is using 9.2GB of space
3. After replication becomes up to date **slave2** is using 9.2GB of space

**master** reports the following:

```
 SELECT slot_name, active, wal_status, safe_wal_size
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_replication_slots;
 slot_name | active | wal_status | safe_wal_size
-----------+--------+------------+---------------
 replica_1 | t      | reserved   |    8598896640
```

**slave** reports the following:

```
SELECT slot_name, active, wal_status, safe_wal_size
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_replication_slots;
 slot_name | active | wal_status | safe_wal_size
-----------+--------+------------+---------------
 replica_1 | t      | reserved   |  124570828800
```

Even though both machines are configured alike, (default params except for the following)

```
wal_level = logical         # minimal, replica, or logical
max_slot_wal_keep_size = 8192   # in megabytes; -1 disables
wal_log_hints = on          # also do full page writes of non-critical updates
```

Why does the middle slave think it should provide more than 12GB of WAL space?

I re-created the DB and replication setup on **slave** now I get:

```
 SELECT slot_name, active, wal_status, safe_wal_size
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_replication_slots;
 slot_name | active | wal_status | safe_wal_size
-----------+--------+------------+---------------
 replica_1 | t      | reserved   |  447666454528
```

This `safe_wal_size` is now in excess of the disk space on the machine, so effectively it can run the machine out of disk space if **slave2** goes down and does not get back up quickly enough.....

Comment: It's not that it _should_, it's that it _can_.

Comment: It's been told to use 8GB for WAL replication, the first machine does, but it chooses to use 12GB which does not make sense given the config

Comment: Perhaps looking at the source code will be helpful.

Comment: I did, and the number is effectively calculated as `slot's restart_lsn + max(max_slot_wal_keep_size, wal_keep_size) - current LSN`. So I'd look at `restart_lsn` of the slot and `pg_current_wal_lsn()` on both servers.